# Write to csv with columns as list in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a list that looks like:

```
[('CarrierDel', '1973.0', '4227.0', '518.0', '2701.0', '3249.0', '7354.0', '980.0', '428.0', '394.0'), ('CarrierID', '9E', 'AA', 'AS', 'B6', 'DL', 'EV', 'F9', 'FL', 'HA'), ('Delays', '3626.0', '8394.0', '1071.0', '3880.0', '5927.0', '13836.0', '1461.0', '1254.0', '303.0')]
```

where 'CarrierDel', 'CarrierID' and 'Delays' are my headers. I want to write this to a csv file. Is there an equivalent to writerow but for columns? Or is there another way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could compile the three together making rows instead of columns e.g. change what you supplied to something like `[('CarrierDel', 'CarrierID', 'Delays')...]` and so on. Something like a matrix transpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(open("some_file.txt","w"))
w.writerows(zip(*list_of_cols))
```

should do it

zip transposes a 2d array(among other things) as seen below

```
 a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
 #transpose a with zip
 print zip(*a)  #prints [(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9)]
```

Comment: So that does work for me. But how come when I use with open(output.csv, 'w') as ouput: it separates each item in the csv file?

Comment: Sorry I'll try to clarify. When I use exactly what you gave me, it works np. When I try using `with open('output.csv', 'w')...` my output looks like "['CarrierDel', 'CarrierID', 'Delays']","['1973.0', '9E', '3626.0']","['4227.0', 'AA', '8394.0']","['518.0', 'AS', '1071.0']","['2701.0', 'B6', '3880.0']","['3249.0', 'DL', '5927.0']","['7354.0', 'EV', '13836.0']","['980.0', 'F9', '1461.0']","['428.0', 'FL', '1254.0']","['394.0', 'HA', '303.0']"

Comment: no you need to use the csv module ... or manually manage your array ... you cant just write it to a file ...